# Why are there two versions of operator new overload?

Tags: c++, new-operator, c++14, iso

What's the reason to have separate overloads for `new` and `new[]` named `operator new` and `operator new[]`? As they both are only used to allocate certain amount of memory - why would I want to write different code for each of them?

Comment: `new[]` also stores the array size before the actual storage for the array

Comment: For instance you want to have a memory pool for small objects. And your pool does not support allocation of arrays of objects. So you leave `operator new[]` default.

Comment: They wanted to allow implementations the chance to optimize allocations of single objects by not needing to store the size of the allocation somewhere.

Comment: I think this is needed only for calling proper amount of destructors at deallocation time. But isn't this done implicitly anyway?

Comment: `delete[]` tells the implementation it should *look* for the number of objects to destroy. But if `new` is used, this information may not be stored.

Answer (score 1):

`new` is used to create a single object

```
int * foo = new int;  // now I have one int*
```

`new[]` is used to create multiple objects and puts them into contiguous memory (array)

```
int * bar = new int[someIntegerValue];
```

When using new you need to make sure that you match it with the correct `delete` call.  If you use `new` you need to have a corresponding call to `delete` and the same goes for `new[]` and `delete[]`

```
int * foo = new int;  // now I have one int*
//more code...
// now that I'm done with foo
delete foo;

int * bar = new int[someIntegerValue];
//more code...
// now that I'm done with bar.
delete [] bar;
```

Comment: This doesn't explain *why* there are two seperate overloads. `new` could redirect to `new[]` but only passing a size of 1 object. But it doesn't. That's the question.

Comment: @NeilKirk Wouldn't that then let you allocate a single int and delete[] it?

Comment: @Alex Maybe, I was referring to a hypothetical language, not C++

Answer (score 0):

Memory allocation optimization since you do not need to store the array size as suggested in a comment is **not** the reason (in fact, the default behavior of `operator new[]` per 18.6.1.2 is to call `operator new` for allocating the storage).
Also, the allocation size is stored for every allocation in every real-world implementation anyway (from which the array size can be trivially deduced).

The decisive reason why you need two versions of `new` is that an array version is generally desirable (for obvious reasons) but the array version cannot have an initializer. Having an initializer on a single new expression, however, is highly desirable. Hence, two separate versions are needed.

Also, some optimized allocators (such as e.g. a freelist) are trivially easy to implement for singular objects but very hard with contiguous arrays. A freelist with 10 elements does not necessarily have 10 *contiguous* elements (or even *two* contiguous ones!), so there is no easy way this could work reliably for array allocations.
Which means that without two separate versions of `new`, you simply wouldn't be able to implement such a thing. Having two versions, you can still use a custom allocator for one, but not for the other.

As a "bonus" that comes for free, you are able to override (and `=delete`) the two operators individually, if, for some reason, you wish to handle them significantly different or selectively do not wish to allow one of them.